# My weather app crashes

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a weather app. if you enter a city name then it gives you the weather info but the app crashes if you enter a wrong city name.

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while (data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();

            }
            return result;


        } catch (RuntimeException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        } catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        return null;
```

error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
              Process: com.example.android.whatstheweather, PID: 10206
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
```

Comment: I dont think you have included enough crash logs. But based on your try catch, I dont think you can call Toast from doInBackground. You also missed off `.show()` from it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your toast, used UI thread to show toast

```
Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: You have missed `.show()` as per OP as well. This should really be done in `onPostExecute()`. Along the correct lines though :)

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean flag=false; // declare boolean  at the top of the class it's a class variable



public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while (data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();

            }
            if(result.isEmpty()){
            flag=false;
            }else{
            flag=true;
            }   
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(!flag){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the typed input you can display a list of city names to choose from, that way a wrong or incorrect input won't enter.

or

Create a check for the city name to see if it's a valid city name if it is not, don't let it proceed any further. Maybe even provide a suggestion of city names by matching the spelling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Toast into Main Thread, use runOnUiThread, or return a string and print the return with a toast in your Activity.